# PIX exception - unable to find valid certification path

Tags: quarkus-rest-client

I am running mvnw compile Quarkus:dev command from command line for a sample project - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/rest-client-quickstart but it keeps thowing below exception ---
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What could be missing?
Thanks,

Application should have compiled successfully